# stop wacth files with tsc -w in npm

Tags: npm, package.json

I am working on angular2 and I want to stop the browser from refresh every change in every file.I have call in package.json to

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
```

if I remove the tsc from the start, I cant see change in files even after refersh the browser.

any idea how to stop the watch on files and still be able to refersh the browser and see changes?

this is the full package.json

```
{
  "name": "product-management",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "avi golan",
  "description": "Package for the Acme Product Management sample application",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.5",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.16.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just added bs-config.json file with to the root folder

```
{
"codeSync": false
}
```